# functions random from database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a function:

```
function nomor_registrasi() {
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from pendaftaran order by no_registrasi DESC LIMIT 0,1");
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $kodeawal=substr($data['no_registrasi'],6,7)+1;
    if($kodeawal<10) {
        $kode='SMKGJ00'.$kodeawal;
    } else if ($kodeawal > 9 && $kodeawal <=99) {
        $kode='SMKGJ0'.$kodeawal;
    } else {
        $kode='SMKGJ'.$kodeawal;
    }
    return $kode;
}
```

If a user registers from a form, the user will have `no_registrasi`, for example: last `no_registrasi` record in the table is **SMKGJ006**, so the user will have **SMKGJ007**, etc..

I'm starting learning the php framework: **laravel**.

How can I code this function using **laravel**?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is there anything you have attempted and are having trouble with?

Comment: i want migrate from old phpmysqlm to laravel framework, now i dont know how to do with that function, generate no_registrasi for user on form registrastion

Comment: If I understand correctly, I believe you have several steps you will need to familiarize yourself with before you can get to an answer.  Your function can still work, but you will need to extract the sql parts and add into Laravel Models.  The standard 'user' model has a pre-made migration that you can add a 'no_registrasi' field to, and then have access to that user field within the registration process (you can add the $kode val to the user model at registration via $user->no_registrasi or simliar.  But, need to create the DB table correctly in the migration first.

Comment: Improved english grammar.

Comment: don't even attempt to port this code - it has an obvious race condition. just have a normal autoincrementing id column, and add the prefix `SMKGJ` in another column (or in pho)

Comment: What you already do in laravel?

Comment: Mysql had been depr. Use Myqli* or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

I use **laravel 4**!

If you want to put your function to run when user register you need to put it in **Controller** that respond for registration of users.

The **Controllers** are in folder `/app/controllers` .

If you **recent(1 minute ago) installed **laravel 4.1** and not have the **Controller** that respond for **registration** of users (like me, after installation I have a page on with is only image and `you arrived` and no link to register and login like after installation of **yii**), when you need to **create it**.

To create controller `UsersController` put in `/app/controllers` file with name **UsersController.php** and code:

```
<?php

 class UsersController extends BaseController {

//!!show the form for registration from root /app/views/some_file name_like_register.blade.php in witch is html form
public function getRegister() {
    return View::make('users/register');
}

    //!! register user when post data come from form
    public function postRegister() {

       //Here you can put your function                    

    $rules = User::$validation;

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('public/users/register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->fill(Input::all());
    $id = $user->register(); 
    return $this->getMessage("Registered successfull.");
}
}
```

Add changes to `User` model. After

```
 class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

add

```
     //form validation
     public static $validation = array(
    'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'username'  => 'required|alpha_num|unique:users',
    'password'  => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
     );

     //for registration 
     protected $fillable = array('username', 'email', 'password');


    //
    public function register() {

       //Here you can put your function                  

    $this->password = Hash::make($this->password);
    $this->activationCode = $this->generateCode();
    $this->save();
    Log::info("User [{$this->email}] registered. Activation code: {$this->activationCode}");

    /*$this->sendActivationMail();*/ //send email with activation code, set 1 to isActive value
    return $this->id;
    }

protected function sendActivationMail() { /*do*/}

protected function generateCode() {
    return Str::random();
}
```

Make file with name `register.blade.php` in `/app/views/` with code:

```
 @section('title')  
 @section('content')

 <div class="container">
 @if ($errors->all())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <p>{{ $error }}</p>
        @endforeach
    </div>
 @endif

<h1>Registration</h1>
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/users/register', 'role' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'E-Mail', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::email('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('username', 'login', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::text('username', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password', 'password', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'retype pass', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

In table user add your `registraci` cell. Table structure is

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) { 
        $table->increments('id'); 
        $table->string('email')->unique(); 
        $table->string('password', 60); 
        $table->string('username')->unique(); 
        $table->boolean('isAdmin'); 
        $table->boolean('isActive')->index(); 
        $table->string('activationCode'); 
        $table->rememberToken(); 
        $table->timestamps(); 


        // also add your registraci
        $table->string('registraci', 200); 


        });
```

To turn on database driver open `/app/config/database.php` and change if need

```
     //select mysql or other 
'default' => 'mysql'

         ...
     //database and other change here
     'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost', 
        'database'  => 'laravel', 
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    )
```

If I lost something you will get errors messages not like `oops` but real problems
To see errors go to `/app/config/app.php` and set to

```
    'debug' => true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with name `no_registrasi` in laravel table with users and use your old code when register new user, only change table name and other columns name.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->string('no_registrasi');
});
```

Comment: give me detail, im just newbie, ty

Comment: how to call nomor_registrasi() and where?

Comment: @Rama Diansyah S  in the registration controller

Comment: How? I dont know, sorry for my noobest:((

Comment: in php i just do $blabbla=nomor_registrasi(); then, $query = insert into user (...., .... , $blabbla), i completely blank on laravel,  or another php framework

Comment: for now work using str_random(5) but i want use my old function